# AsyncLock for multiple methods configuration

Tags: c#, locking, async-await

What I need to achieve is:

1. When MasterAsync is executing, HumbleSlave1Async and HumbleSlave2Async can NOT.
2. Vice Versa- When one or both of Slaves are executing, MasterAsync can NOT.
3. Difficult part- Slaves can NOT block each other.

(Link to used [AsyncLock](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx)).

```
    private async Task MasterAsync()
    {
        using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
    private async Task HumbleSlave1Async()
    {
        using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
    private async Task HumbleSlave2Async()
    {
        using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to solve it, was thinking about use of two different locks for each slave in MasterAsync but then one lock would be in another:

```
    private async Task MasterAsync()
    {
        using (await _asyncLock1.LockAsync())
        {
            using (await _asyncLock2.LockAsync())
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        }
    }
    private async Task HumbleSlave1Async()
    {
        using (await _asyncLock1.LockAsync())
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
    private async Task HumbleSlave2Async()
    {
        using (await _asyncLock2.LockAsync())
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

Does it make sense and is it safe(deadlocks, etc...) especially when I used AsyncLock ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When MasterAsync is executing, HumbleSlave1Async and HumbleSlave2Async can NOT.
>   Vice Versa- When one or both of Slaves are executing, MasterAsync can NOT.
>   Difficult part- Slaves can NOT block each other.

First, double-check whether you really want this. The majority of the time, a restructuring of the code responsibilities will simplify what synchronization you need (and is usually more efficient, too).

That said, your scenario fits a reader/writer lock. A RWL is a lock that can be taken two different ways, as a "writer" (which does not allow any other locks at the same time) or as a "reader" (which allows other readers but not writers). Stephen Toub has an `async`-compatible one [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10267069.aspx) and I have one as part of my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncReaderWriterLock&referringTitle=Documentation).

**Update:** Example code:

```
private readonly AsyncReaderWriterLock _lock = new AsyncReaderWriterLock();
private async Task MasterAsync()
{
    using (await _lock.WriterLockAsync())
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
private async Task HumbleSlave1Async()
{
    using (await _lock.ReaderLockAsync())
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
private async Task HumbleSlave2Async()
{
    using (await _lock.ReaderLockAsync())
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: "First, double-check" Ok, checked and I am sure of all conditions: both slaves must be able to execute parallelly and while executing them Master can not execute because it would change some variables that are used by Slaves.

Comment: I did read recommended article. Can't get it working. If Slaves would use WriterLockAsync() (different for each) and Master would use two ReaderLockAsync() accordingly, it would still block in avo's scenario(look at avo's answer) Can you please suggest how to use AsyncReaderWriterLock in my case?

Comment: Updated with example code. You would only have one RWL, with "master" locking as a writer and each "slave" locking as a reader. BTW, what I meant by "double-check whether you want this" is to *re-examine your design* that got you to this point; see if there's a cleaner alternative design.

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem with your approach is that when `HumbleSlave2Async` is executing, and `MasterAsync` has been called, acquired `asyncLock1` and is awaiting `asyncLock2`, you won't be able to execute `HumbleSlave1Async` (because `asyncLock1` is taken by `MasterAsync`). So, your condition #3 will not be satisfied.

Maybe you should use something like [AsyncManualResetEvent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx) to make this work.

Comment: You could say that it's the waiting master that's blocking the second slave, not the working slave, so #3 would be satisfied.

Comment: @svick, yes you can say so, depending on how you look at it. So `MasterAsync` is blocking, `HumbleSlave2Asyn` is executing, but `HumbleSlave1Async` will be blocking because there is already a call to `MasterAsync`. Maybe OP should clarify if that's OK.

Comment: @avo, you're right, as you described can not execute HumbleSlave1Async when MasterAsync was called while HumbleSlave2Async is working. I did read [AsyncManualResetEvent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx) but have no idea how it could help. Anyway thanks. Trying use bools inside of Slaves.

Comment: @as74, is that also a requirement that `HumbleSlave1Asyn`/`HumbleSlave2Asyn` are allowed to be re-entered multiple times from other thread, or recursively? Or just once per each?

Comment: @avo, real purpose of HumbleSlaves is opening of orders(buy/sell currencies). It is possible (if open order not succeeded) that one or both HumbleSlaves will be executed recursively. In the meantime Master can not be executed. HumbleSlaves are async Tasks and all inside is in await Task.Run(async () =>

Comment: @as74, so what's wrong with the Stephen's example: `WriterLockAsync` for master, `ReaderLockAsync` for slaves, sharing the same `_lock` object between all three?

Comment: @avo, when HumbleSlave2Async is executing and MasterAsync has been called, and then HumbleSlave1Async has been called, the Master(WriterLockAsync) take precedence over readers in this case HumbleSlave1Async. As a result Master would execute between Slaves. What should be done is probably use Stephen's example adding bools to Slaves slave1Executing = true; and prohibit calling Master when slave1Executing or lave2Executing == true. Thank you guys.

Comment: @as74, `bool` is not enough because recursion/reentrancy is possible. You need an awaitable object with mutex-like behavior. The object should have a **counter** inside and should keep track of the ownership acquisitions using an id. Slaves would share the same id, master would use a separate one. I can't help with the code right now, but I may cook up something over the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not going to deadlock because you acquire locks always in the same order:

1. `_asyncLock1` (or you don't acquire it for `HumbleSlave2Async`)
2. `_asyncLock2` (or you don't acquire it for `HumbleSlave1Async`)

A total lock order guarantees freedom of deadlocks.